# d3.js transition().remove() not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with a visualization in d3.js.

I have three groups containing almost identical visualizations, being a take on "multiple small" visualizations. The visualization incorporates a timeline, upon change of which appropriate data points have to be added/removed. Here's the code that does the updating:

```
var channels = { bt: { x: 0, y: -100 }, sms: { x: -300, y: 200 }, call: { x: 300, y: 200 } };
        //Draw web for each channel
        for (channel in channels) {
            this.circles[channel] = this.web[channel].selectAll("circle")
                   .data(this.displayedNodes, function (d) {
                       return d.id;
                   });

            this.circles[channel].exit().transition().duration(500).attr("r", 0).remove();

            this.circles[channel].enter()
                   .append("circle")
                   .attr("class", "person")
                   .attr("r", 0)
                   .attr("cx", function (d) {
                       return d.friendScales[channel](chart.minScores[channel]).x;
                   })
                   .attr("cy", function (d) {
                       return d.friendScales[channel](chart.minScores[channel]).y;
                   })
                   .attr("fill", function (d) {
                       //return chart.clusterColors[d.cluster];
                       return chart.colors[channel];
                   })
                   .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                   .attr("stroke", function (d) {
                       return d3.rgb(chart.colors[channel]).darker();
                   })
                   .attr("id", function (d) {
                       return "bubble_" + d.id;
                   })
                   .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
                       return chart.show_details(d, i, this);
                   })
                   .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
                       return chart.hide_details(d, i, this);
                   });
        }
```

The .exit().transition().remove() part does nothing, the circles just slide away, as their data value is now 0. However if I open the Chrome console and manually type in exactly the same thing this evaluates to, it works fine. I assume this has something to do with JavaScript's asynchronous model, I'm not a JS wiz, so I am a bit at a loss here, this should be fine in any other language...

Any ideas are much appreciated!

To add from the comments, as they are becoming huge:

Working example: http://www.student.dtu.dk/~s103826/
Code: https://github.com/haljin/d3-webchart/blob/master/Sensible/js/WebChart.js

To see the problem: Drag the grey rectangle on the timeline (resize by draggin edges) onto the area at the end, that does not have data - the circles should disappear as per `exit().transition().remove()` but don't. If I set a break point at that area however and type the same in the Chrome console, they do.

Comment: It should work like that -- can you post a complete working example please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Here is the working example: [link](http://www.student.dtu.dk/~s103826/)
And here's the full code: [link](https://github.com/haljin/d3-webchart/blob/pawel/Sensible/js/WebChart.js)

Comment: The example looks ok to me -- I don't see any shrinking circles. Where exactly is it going wrong?

Comment: If you select the time period where there is no data as indicated by the timeline (the very end) the circles should disappear completely, as `this.displayedNodes` is []

Comment: I can't seem to select anything on the timeline...

Comment: The brush is slightly too large, it's in the middle of being changed. You can drag by the edges of the grey area to resize and then move it to the end

Comment: Right, it looks like immediately after the loop, you're starting new transitions for all the circles. This will overwrite any previous transitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Lars for help, I was re-selecting all circles, rather than using the existing update selection `this.circles` :)

I feel silly now.