# Replacing a d3.js path transition with a new one?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961437/d3-js-transition-remove-not-working) question and [many other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784018/how-can-i-remove-or-replace-svg-content) examples, but it isn't helping. I'm trying the last example on [this page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) and after 5 seconds, I want the curved path that is being drawn, to completely disappear and 5 more seconds later, I want a new path to be created.

I've tried the below code, but although the entire `svg` element itself is removed, when I use appendGraph() to created the `svg` and the path again, the same old path re-appears. How can I ensure that the old path is completely removed and that the tick function also does not get called when the graph is removed?

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nav9/5uygqj9v/

And the code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style>
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.noselect {
/* these are to disable text selection */
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

rect.zoom {
stroke: steelblue;
fill-opacity: 0.3;
}

#placeholder {margin: 10px 5px 15px 70px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="placeholder" ></div>
<script>
//---------globals
var timer = null, interval = 500, value = 0;
var value1 = 0;
var n = 143, duration = interval, now = new Date(Date.now() - duration), count = 0, data = d3.range(n).map(function() { return 0; });

var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 50, left: 60}, width = 580 - margin.right, height = 420 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-1, 1]).range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
            .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
            .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });
var svg, path, yaxis, axis;



//--------program starts
appendGraph();
tick();
value1 = 0;
setTimeout(function() {removeGraph();}, 5000);
setTimeout(function() {addGraphAgain();}, 10000);



//-------------------------------functions -------------------------------
function appendGraph()
{
  svg = d3.select("body").select("#placeholder").append("p").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("id", "mainSVG")
    .style("margin-left", -margin.left + "px")
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

axis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

yaxis = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(y.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .data([data])
    .attr("id", "line1")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .style("visibility","visible");

}//appendGraph

//TODO: These tick functions could be simplified to handle more lines on the graph
function tick() 
{
  // push the accumulated count onto the back, and reset the count
  value1 = Math.random() * 100;
  if (value1 >= 0) {data.push(value1);} else {data.push(0);}//ensure that no NaN or undefined values corrupt the range

  // update the domains
  now = new Date();
  x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);

  count = 0;
  // redraw the lines
  svg.select("#line1").attr("d", line).attr("transform", null);

  // slide the line left
  path.transition().duration(duration).ease("linear").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")").each("end", tick);
  y.domain([0, 100]);
  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0]);      
  yaxis.call(y.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));  

  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();
  console.log("tick being called");
}

function removeGraph()
{
    path.transition().duration(0).each(function() { this.__transition__.active = 0; });//at least this is stopping tick from being called   
    svg.selectAll("*").remove();
    //-------tried these too
//  d3.select("#mainSVG").remove("svg");
//  d3.select("#line1").remove("path");
//  path.remove();
    //d3.selectAll("path").attr("d", "Z");
    console.log("REMOVED");
}//removeGraph

function addGraphAgain()
{
    appendGraph();

    tick();

    value1 = 0; 
    console.log("ADDED AGAIN");
}//addGraphAgain
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exact answer to this question, but since the reason I asked this was because I wanted to have phases where I wanted to send null inputs to the graph and there seemed no other way to do it other than to remove the line and replace it with a new line.

The trick to handle null or NaN data or missing data in d3.js or to simply not display data for a while is to use [defined](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined).

A working example of it [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090) and in the line transition, it's like this:
I supply a random number at `if (counter%5==0) ran = null;data.push(ran);` and `.defined(function(d) { return d != null; })` takes care of the null, by not drawing a line there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var n = 40,
    random = d3.random.normal(0, .2),
    data = d3.range(n).map(random);

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, n - 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-1, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d != null; })
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

var path = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

var counter = 0;    
tick();

function tick() 
{
  // push a new data point onto the back
  var ran = random();
  counter++;
  if (counter%5==0) ran = null;
  data.push(ran);

  // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
  path
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null)
    .transition()
      .duration(500)
      .ease("linear")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")
      .each("end", tick);

  // pop the old data point off the front
  data.shift();
}

</script>
```